# java.awt.Robot keyPress() Method typing incorrectly

Tags: java

I am experiencing an error in my program. Not a compilation error, but an error in the execution of the program itself. When calling my type() method, the String is typed if and only if there are no capital letters ( I have tried changing the Strings ). And random characters are being typed in place of the characters of the string. Any helpful insight, or just to know that I am not alone would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.lang.Character;
import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;
public class TicketMaker
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Robot robot = null;
        String lottoMessage = "Vindex Lotto Ticket # ";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Running program", "Ticket Master", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        try
        {
            robot = new Robot(); 
        }
        catch(AWTException e)
        {
            String err = "Could not instantiate Robot class!";
            errprint(err);
            System.exit(-1);
        }


        try
        {
             robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E); //Open book
             Thread.sleep(2000);
             type(lottoMessage, robot);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            errprint("Could not begin book writing"); 
        }
    }
    public static void errprint(String m)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error! " + m);
    }
    public static void type(String toType, Robot robo)
    {
         char character;
         int ascii;
         int limit = toType.length(); //11
         int i;
         for( i = 0; i < limit; i++)
         {
            character = toType.charAt(i);
            ascii = (int)character;
            robo.keyPress(ascii);
         }
     try
     {
        Thread.sleep(500);
     }
     catch(InterruptedException e)
     {
        errprint("Sleep failed!");
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send capital letters through Robot you have to type a shift.  Also for any of the special characters above the numbers.  Robot works exactly like typing on your own keyboard.

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

And after you call keyPress, call keyRelease to simulate taking your finger off the key.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I don't know how I thought of that!